# c# File Checksum Function

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm creating this function to check if all my files are still correct or wether some files are missing.

So far I've managed to obtain a list with Files from the root directory, and another list with all it's hashes.

I also have managed to create a healthy hash text file. which contains the Hash 3 tabs (so it's easier readable in notepad) and then the file name from root.

eg.

```
3914ea0985f3f67a8204685beb6d1be6            \file1.extension
2ed432f68ab6ebfc32664409482f0de2            \folder1\file2.extension
```

Each ends up in a seprate list so now I have 4 lists.

I was wondering whether i should use dictionaries instead to reduce 4 lists to 2 dictionaries.

Thus the filename (plus any subdirectory) would be the key, and the value would be the hash.

```
KEY                                 VALUE
\file1.extension                    3914ea0985f3f67a8204685beb6d1be6
\folder1\file2.extension            2ed432f68ab6ebfc32664409482f0de2
```

My assumption is that by doing this, I can check for missing files and delete those keys from the dictionary with the healthy hashes. So that I can check existing files equally against each other. (just based on index).

Below this my current codes to get the stuff required.

This gets the file list:

```
    public List<string> Get_FileList(string root)
    {
        List<string> FileList = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(name => 
        { 
            return
                !(name.EndsWith("dmp") || name.EndsWith("jpg") ||                               //exclude dmp and image files
                name.EndsWith("FileChecker.exe"));                                             //exclude myself
        }).ToList();

        return FileList;
    }
```

This gets the hashes:

```
    public List<string> Get_FileHash(List<string> FileList)
    {
        List<string> FileHash = new List<string>();
        foreach (string FileName in FileList)
        {
            FileStream file = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
            file.Close();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            FileHash.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        return FileHash;
    }
```

This gets the healthy hashes:

```
public void Get_HealthyHash(string file, out List<string> Healthy_FileList, out List<string> Healthy_HashList) 
    {
        string resource= "FileCheckSum.Resources." + file;

        Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        Healthy_FileList = new List<string>();
        Healthy_HashList = new List<string>();

        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] items = line.Split(new string[] { "\t\t\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Healthy_FileList.Add(items[1]);
            Healthy_HashList.Add(items[0]);
        }

    }
```

And to determine the missing files I use this:

```
IEnumerable<string> Dif_File_list = Healthy_FileList.Except(FileList.Select(name => name.Replace(root, "")));
```

I have to remove the root here since the healthy hash file does not have the path from C:\

So as you can see 4 lists, (well 5 after getting the differences).

My question:

How can/should I continue checking the existing files if they are valid from this point? without the missing files interfering.

Any help, improvement on my functions or pointers to continue would be appreciated.
**NOTE** All the code given here works! Be it slow with a great amount of files, as I have not added any sort of threading to make it faster.

Comment: Your code could be cleaned up and streamlined a little but it's only slow because you (have to) use `md5.ComputeHash(file)`. That's not going to change.

Comment: Yea I know about the clean up, this is just the rough version. any alternative to make it faster? currently it takes about 30-35 seconds to compute all the hashes.

Comment: But still should I use dictionaries or not? so that the hash that belongs to file X does not get mixed up with that of file Y.

Comment: Dictionaries or  Tuples... You left out the consuming part.There is a special site for code-reviews.

Comment: This is not really about code review though, just a How to proceed from where. I have say 1000 healthy hashes (of 1000 files respectively). I want to compare it to the files in from the current root, but only 995 files are present (5 random files are missing, thus 5 hashes less to check). Hence my question would dictionaries ease my problem? How to check the files effectively without missing files interfering?

Answer (score 1):

Make an entity class MyFileInfo with string properties FileName and HashValue. Implement IEqualityComparer, override Equals and GetHashCode methods.

Then load healthy List< MyFileInfo> from file and build toExamine List< MyFileInfo> from current directory.

Use LINQ methods to find differences between lists.

Look here 
[LINQ Distinct, Except, Contains, Union, Intersect and IEqualityComparer](http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2009/06/23/Enumerable-Except-TSource-and-IEqualityComparer-a-little-help.aspx)